# How do i fix SCP not working from inside Makefile

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, makefile, scp

I am trying to write a c++ program on my windows machine, build it using a makefile, and deploy it using make deploy.

This is where i run in to problems...

The Make for compiling works fine, and manual scp in cmd works fine aswell but when i copy my scp command in to my makefile and run it using make deploy it's not working...

Make file:

```
C:\Users\sekl\OneDrive - FORCE Technology\Repos\New folder>make deploy
scp Hello root@192.168.200.10:/usr/bin
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, scp Hello root@192.168.200.10:/usr/bin, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:26: deploy] Error 2
```

Manual SCP:

```
C:\Users\sekl\OneDrive - FORCE Technology\Repos\New folder>scp Hello root@192.168.200.10:/usr/bin
Hello 100%   13KB 208.6KB/s   00:00
```

My Makefile looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

%.o:    %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

ioctl:  Hello.o
    $(CXX) -o Hello $(LDFLAGS) Hello.o

all:    Hello

.PHONY: clean deploy

 deploy:
    scp Hello root@192.168.200.10:/usr/bin

clean:
    rm -f Hello *.o
```

Comment: What happens if you use the full path to `scp`?  I'm a bit confused as to which file is being referred to in the `cannot find the file specified` message.

Comment: How do i do that? I am not used to working with windows..

Comment: Provide the absolute path to the location of the `scp` executable.  On linux, for example, it would probably be something like `/usr/bin/scp` .

Comment: Still no luck.. Tried with bot the absolute path for scp and also the Hello file I am trying to compile over